# Point connection in QGIS

Tags: qgis, points-to-line

I have to connect points to a polygon. I tried to use "points to path" and "point connector" plugins in QGIS, but neither of them are working.
For testing, I just drew 4 points and used "points to path" and "point connector". The created layer does not contain any features. 
I did the same with importing 4 points from a txt file, the result is the same. 
Is there some trick on how to use those plugins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two steps in order to create polygons from points.

First, use `points to path` or `convert points to line(s)`. You can find both tools in the toolbox. Important:

1. The algorithm needs to know, which point comes first in a line. Number them accordingly.
2. The algorithm needs to know, which line a point belongs to, identify them accordingly.
3. In order to achieve closed lines/rings/loops, your starting points needs to double as ending point. Digitize a second point right on top of it, but give it the last number of the line they both belong to instead of the first.

Second, run `convert lines to polygons`, also from the toolbox.