# How to manually create polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have all my points laid out on my map and i need to connect these points to create polygons. The points are pretty hectic and close together, but I need them created a certain way, so i was wondering how I can do that. I've tried Points2polygon and while it does create a polygon its not what im looking for.

I just think it would be easier to manually connect the dots because I know what they're supposed to look like.

Comment: If you decide to connect them manually, try it with [snapping](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/278376/81764).

Comment: Or  number your points in the order you want them connected, and follow the solution outlined [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/300553/81764).